# jqGrid getting data from url option

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

I am having the hardest time pulling data out of my url and putting it in my jqGrid in asp.net MVC4. What am I missing here?

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#frTable").jqGrid ({
            cmTemplate: { sortable: false },
            caption: '@TempData["POPNAME"]' + ' Population',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetAjaxPagedGridData", "Encounters", new { popId = TempData["POPULATIONID"] })',//'/Encounters/GetAjaxPagedGridData/'+ '',
            datatype: "jsonstring",
            mtype: 'GET',
            pager: '#pager',
            height: '450',
            ...
```

Then you go into the colNames and colModels and all that stuff which is tangential to this particular inquiry. Here is the methods that return my data.  Suffice it to say that the stuff that I do to do client side paging seems to work. But I can't verify unless I can actually see the data?

What am I doing wrong here?

```
    public string GetAjaxPagedGridData(int page, int rows, int popId) {
        string userID = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        DataRepository dr = new DataRepository();
        string encounter = dr.Get(popId, userID, "1", page, rows, "");
        return encounter;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `postData` option of jqGrid in the form

```
postData: {
    popId: 123
}
```

or in the form

```
postData: {
    popId: function () {
        return 123;
    }
}
```

You should use additionally `datatype: "json"` instead of `datatype: "jsonstring"`.

Comment: I don't know what it is, but when I put datatype into my options, I always get this exception... 
'Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property '0': object is null or undefined'  pretty sure that this is no good.

Comment: @DmainEvent: The exception could mean many other errors like wrong format data which you return from `GetAjaxPagedGridData` or wrong order of JavaScript files which you use. See [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:first_grid#html_file).